# Programmatically creating a Wireless Access Point in C#

Tags: c#, windows, wireless

I would like to create a Wireless Access Point on my machine programmatically through C#.NET.
I have been trying to find a way to implement this, but cannot get a good solution.

Most solutions I came across only allowed me enough control to connect to an Access Point, not create one.

This code should work on Windows 7 and above. Although, if it can work on Windows XP, it would be a great advantage (but not a requirement).

Comment: The source code here may be of interest: http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/

Comment: That should also work. Thanks! Looking into the code right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use built-in functionality. Call these shell commands from your program:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=<NetworkName> key=<AccessKey> keyUsage=persistent
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I need to do this programatically. Require this for deployment on client side.

Comment: It looks pretty programmatic to me! If you mean from c#, you can run this by launching a bat file or just running it directly via `Process.Start(...)`

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie: I should make this cleaer. I was hoping there would be a native way to do this from .NET code instead of executing Shell Scripts.

Comment: @darnir, executing external programs is a very native method to solve tasks. But if this solution is not enough challenging, you can try to achieve the same using WMI network configuration facilities. ;)

Comment: Guess I'll use this method itself. Thanks!

Comment: Will not work, because it requires Administrator privileges.  It is not "programmatic" if it stops and demands a password each time.  And each successive trick, such as "start an admin shell first" or "use powershell" is still roadblocked by the Admin password requirement.

Comment: the netssh return this error when I try to start hotspot :
The hosted network couldn't be started.
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.